# Storing all values of a rnorm sample in large quantities (vector) for a Tukey test later

Tags: r, arrays, loops, dplyr, simulation

So I think I'm almost there! What im trying to do is create a script where you fill in "expected means (mu)" and "standard deviations (sd)" of two populations and as output you get a table where you show the fraction of significant differences found between these two populations (determined by ANOVA and Tukey test) based on the sample size. Expecting of-course, that the higher the sample size, the higher te fraction of significant results will be. Now something strange happens, when I compare two means (200 an 260) both with sd=30, it seems that the fraction of significant p-values is randomly distributed over the sample sizes (below I used sample size 1,2,3...9). What I hoped to find is that as sample size increases the fraction of significant differences detected by ANOVA and Tukey will increase as well due to how ANOVA works. Higher sample sizes will lead to more solid models and thus more solid p-values. What I expected was
something like this:

```
n   fraction significant
1        0.1
2        0.3
3        0.4
4        0.6
5        0.8
6        0.9
```

This doesn't happen, I get something like this:

```
n   fraction significant
1        0.1
2        0.0
3        0.2
4        0.4
5        0.0
6        0.1
```

I think this is because initially when I run my loops and rnorm, it only stores one value as a "sample" per initial sample size: e.g. for initial sample size n=1 and "exp"=1 (these are my iterations) I get 1 randomly generated sample value, which is logical. But for n=9 and "exp=1" I too only get one value instead of 9 values. I should put in 9 values into the ANOVA and Tukey in this case, probably yielding higher amounts of "exp" iterations resulting in a significant difference. I think if I manage to achieve something like this it should work, I don't know how to do manage though, I tried for 3 days and I'm stuck:

```
n    sample pop 1         sample pop 2
1    200.4                270.1           compare by ANOVA and Tukey -> p value
1    190.3                234.7           compare by ANOVA and Tukey -> p value
2.   [200.2 184.6]        [260.2 265.3]   compare by ANOVA and Tukey -> p value
2.   [230.1 222.7]        [280.1 204.6]   compare by ANOVA and Tukey -> p value
3.   [270.3 230.1 201.3]  [232.2 222.1]   compare by ANOVA and Tukey -> p value
#etc... 
#(Right now 10 times per n-value, but ultimately I want to do 10.000 iterations)
```

Here is the script I made, I'm sorry to anyone with experience ;)

```
{
  library(tidyverse)
  library(dplyr)
  library(reshape2)
  library(multcomp)
  library(stringr)
}
rm(list=ls())
{
  mu <- 200
  sd <- 30
  n_array_1 <- c()
  exp_array_1 <- c()
  pop_sample_array_1 <- c()
  ID_array_1 <- "population1"
  for (n_1 in c(1:9)) {
    for (exp_1 in c(1:10)) {
      n_array_1 <- c(n_array_1, n_1)
      exp_array_1 <- c(exp_array_1, exp_1)
      population_sample_1 <- rnorm(n_1, mu, sd)
      pop_sample_array_1 <- c(pop_sample_array_1, population_sample_1)
      
    }
}

    mu_2 <- 260
    sd_2 <- 30
    n_array_2 <- c()
    exp_array_2 <- c()
    pop_sample_array_2 <- c()
    ID_array_2 <- "population2"
   
    for (n_2 in c(1:9)) {
      for (exp_2 in c(1:10)) {
        n_array_2 <- c(n_array_2, n_2)
        exp_array_2 <- c(exp_array_2, exp_2)
        population_sample_2 <- rnorm(n_2, mu_2, sd_2)
        pop_sample_array_2 <- c(pop_sample_array_2, population_sample_2)
      
        
      }
}
  
  df1 <- data.frame(n=n_array_1, exp=exp_array_1, sample=pop_sample_array_1, ID=ID_array_1)
  df2 <- data.frame(n=n_array_2, exp=exp_array_2, sample=pop_sample_array_2, ID=ID_array_2)
}

combineddf <- rbind(df1, df2)
view(combineddf)
#
## Running an ANOVA comparing the 2 groups specified
{
  combineddf$IDcombined <- as.factor(paste(combineddf$IDcombined, combineddf$ID, combineddf$n, combineddf$exp,  sep = "_"))
  combineddf$IDcombined <- as.factor(combineddf$IDcombined)
  combineddf
  resaov <- aov(sample ~ IDcombined, data=combineddf)
  test <- TukeyHSD(resaov)
  TK <- test
  TK_data<-as.data.frame(TK[1:1])
  TK_data$IDcombined <- rownames(TK_data)
}
{
LC1 <- separate(TK_data, col=IDcombined, into = c("A", "B"), sep = "-")
LC2 <- separate(LC1, col = A, into=c("ignore", "comparison_factor_1", "sample_size", "iteration"), sep="_")
LC3 <- separate(LC2, col=B, into=c("ignore", "comparison_factor_2", "sample_size_2", "iteration_2"), sep="_")
  }
{
  results <- dplyr::select(LC3, comparison_factor_1, comparison_factor_2, iteration, iteration_2, sample_size, sample_size_2, IDcombined.p.adj)
results <- dplyr::filter(results, comparison_factor_1=="population1" & comparison_factor_2=="population2" |  comparison_factor_1=="population2" & comparison_factor_2=="population1")
results <- dplyr::filter(results, sample_size == sample_size_2 & iteration == iteration_2)
}

#
## calculations of fractions significant p-values of a tukey test comparing the 2 populations based on the different sample sizes

results$significant <- results$IDcombined.p.adj < 0.05
for (sample_size in unique(results$sample_size)) {
  subset_results <- results[results$sample_size == sample_size, ]
  n_significant <- sum(subset_results$significant)
  n_total <- nrow(subset_results)
  fraction_significant <- n_significant / n_total
  cat(sample_size, " ", fraction_significant, "\n")
}
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what are you trying to achieve in first part of script when you make random samples. Just note that length of `n_array_1` and `exp_array_1` is 90 and length of `pop_sample_array` is 450 so when you make `data.frame` first two columns repeat each for 5 times to get to length 450.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Im trying the following: for population 1 I want to generate 10 "samples" (thats why I picked 1:10 for exp_array) containing 1 (n=1), 2 (n=2), 3 (n=3)...9 (n=9) randomly generated values. So this means that for pop1 & n=1 I have 10 values. For pop1 n=5 I should have 5*10=50 values etc. I do the same for pop2. I want then want to compare pop1 values to pop2 values by ANOVA and Tukey grouped by sample size. So for example I want to compare pop1 (n=4) and pop2 (n=4) 10 times in 10 separate ANOVA's and Tukeys. Meaning that 4 values per population go into the ANOVA, 10 times.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to generate random samples of length 1 to 9, 10 time each?

Comment: I managed to do it, I added an answer with the new, full script. As you can see, when you run it, increasing sample sizes lead to increasing significance. I managed to do it by adding another "for" loop. Since this question is highly specific, I can delete the whole post, let me know if I should do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding another "for" loop (with "replicates") fixed my problems. Now I just need to store the output of the "cat" function in a table or dataframe and I can expand the script (adding more groups for comparison) Script below:

```
{
  library(tidyverse)
  library(dplyr)
  library(reshape2)
  library(multcomp)
  library(stringr)
}
rm(list=ls())
#
## Syncom C - (t=10)
{
  {
    mu_1 <- 628
    sd_1 <- 130
    n_array_1 <- c()
    exp_array_1 <- c()
    pop_sample_array_1 <- c()
    ID_array_1 <- "population1"
    for (n_1 in c(1:20)) {
      for (exp_1 in c(1:30)) {
        population_sample_1 <- rnorm(n_1, mu_1, sd_1)
        for (replicate_1 in population_sample_1) {
          n_array_1 <- c(n_array_1, n_1)
          exp_array_1 <- c(exp_array_1, exp_1)
          pop_sample_array_1 <- c(pop_sample_array_1, replicate_1)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
#
## Control - (t=10)
{
  {
    mu_2 <- 423
    sd_2 <- 96
    n_array_2 <- c()
    exp_array_2 <- c()
    pop_sample_array_2 <- c()
    ID_array_2 <- "population2"
    for (n_2 in c(1:20)) {
      for (exp_2 in c(1:30)) {
        population_sample_2 <- rnorm(n_2, mu_2, sd_2)
        for (replicate_2 in population_sample_2) {
          n_array_2 <- c(n_array_2, n_2)
          exp_array_2 <- c(exp_array_2, exp_2)
          pop_sample_array_2 <- c(pop_sample_array_2, replicate_2)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
{  
  df1 <- data.frame(n=n_array_1, exp=exp_array_1, sample=pop_sample_array_1, ID=ID_array_1)
  df2 <- data.frame(n=n_array_2, exp=exp_array_2, sample=pop_sample_array_2, ID=ID_array_2)
}

combineddf <- rbind(df1, df2)
#view(combineddf)
#
## Running an ANOVA comparing the 2 groups specified
{
  combineddf$IDcombined <- as.factor(paste(combineddf$IDcombined, combineddf$ID, combineddf$n, combineddf$exp,  sep = "_"))
  combineddf$IDcombined <- as.factor(combineddf$IDcombined)
  combineddf
  resaov <- aov(sample ~ IDcombined, data=combineddf)
  test <- TukeyHSD(resaov)
  TK <- test
  TK_data<-as.data.frame(TK[1:1])
  TK_data$IDcombined <- rownames(TK_data)
}
{
LC1 <- separate(TK_data, col=IDcombined, into = c("A", "B"), sep = "-")
LC2 <- separate(LC1, col = A, into=c("ignore", "comparison_factor_1", "sample_size", "iteration"), sep="_")
LC3 <- separate(LC2, col=B, into=c("ignore", "comparison_factor_2", "sample_size_2", "iteration_2"), sep="_")
  }
{
  results <- dplyr::select(LC3, comparison_factor_1, comparison_factor_2, iteration, iteration_2, sample_size, sample_size_2, IDcombined.p.adj)
results <- dplyr::filter(results, comparison_factor_1=="population1" & comparison_factor_2=="population2" |  comparison_factor_1=="population2" & comparison_factor_2=="population1")
results <- dplyr::filter(results, sample_size == sample_size_2 & iteration == iteration_2)
}

#
## calculations of fractions significant p-values of a tukey test comparing the 2 populations based on the different sample sizes

results$significant <- results$IDcombined.p.adj < 0.05
for (sample_size in unique(results$sample_size)) {
  subset_results <- results[results$sample_size == sample_size, ]
  n_significant <- sum(subset_results$significant)
  n_total <- nrow(subset_results)
  fraction_significant <- n_significant / n_total
  cat(sample_size, " ", fraction_significant, "\n")
}
```